# About "Hoshi no Hitomi no Silhouette"

Tags: twin-star-exorcists, hoshi-no-hitomi-no-silhouette

In episode 21 of *Sousei no Onmyouji*, Mayura advises Benio to read a manga titled *Hoshino Hitomi no Silhouette* ("Hoshino Hitomi's Silhouette") to learn how to deal with Rokuro romantically.

[image: episode 21, 09:38]

After googling around a bit, I noticed that this work is a clear parody of a work with a homophonous title ― *Hoshi no Hitomi no Silhouette* ("Silhouettes of the Eyes of the Stars"), published 1985-89. The author of the fictional work is "Kaede Akane", whose name means "Maple-tree Red", while the real work is by Hiiragi Aoi, which can be read as meaning "Holly-plant Blue". I point this out to emphasize that this is clearly an allusion of sorts.

Mayura describes this manga as a "bible of romance", supposedly read by four million girls, and shows us these archetypical shoujo-romance scenes from the manga:

[image: "Look me in the eye and" / "tell me that you love me one more time"]
[image]
[image: ("I'm not going to let you go") / "until you tell me how you feel about me"]
[image: lewd]

I don't have any context for *why* the author might have chosen to parody this particular shoujo romance manga, though. Might there be some sort of connection between Sukeno Yoshiaki (author of *Sousei no Onmyouji*) and Hiiragi Aoi? Or is *Hoshi no Hitomi no Silhouette* a particularly classic exemplar of shoujo romance manga?